# Can Nvidia Settings show "10bpc" (10-bit colour depth)?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, wayland

The picture below is found by Google Image search. On Windows, Nvidia settings show 10-bit colour depth for my monitor, but on Linux (installed the latest proprietary driver), Nvidia settings shows only up to 8bpc. My question is, does Nvidia + Linux support 10bpc in the first place? I mean, it would be pointless to try to figure out how to enable 10bpc, if it is not supported on Linux in the first place.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

10bpc depends upon your monitor and card. Assuming both can render 10bpc...

1. Confirm current current bpc by entering command: xwininfo -root | grep Depth
2. Create xorg.conf file by command: sudo nvidia-xconfig
3. Open the xorg.conf file by command: sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
4. Scroll down to where you see the number '24' in the screen section. Change all entries to '30'.
5. save. reboot.
6. Confirm by command: xwininfo -root | grep Depth

Caveats:

1. Only very few number of apps can render 10 bpc; the vast majority render 8; so you will see no improvements. Example: viewnoir cannot, and gives a black screen; but the default image viewer can, and shows the image. At 10 bpc, wallpapers do not appear on home screen: the screen is solid black.
2. see [https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4847/~/how-to-enable-30-bit-color%2F10-bit-per-color-on-quadro%2Fgeforce%3F](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4847/%7E/how-to-enable-30-bit-color%2F10-bit-per-color-on-quadro%2Fgeforce%3F)